# Time delay breaks form targeting iframe

Tags: html, forms, iframe, targeting

I have:

```
<iframe name="form-response" id="form-response" class="hidden" src="" width="0" height="0" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form" target="form-response" method="post" action="https://......">
```

The page is part of a single page app, so it is constructed. After much experimentation, I discovered that putting the form on the page after the page has drawn causes the targeting to fail, and the form submission response opens in a new tab rather than being directed into the iframe. This is true in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Is there some point at which the browser examines its page and decides what targets are on-page vs what should go to a new tab? Is there some way to tell it to look again?

More details:
I'm working in an esoteric JS framework. The page loads, fetches some data, then updates with the fetched data (at which point the form is created and inserted, along with its iframe target element). I stripped the form content down to the bare minimum (a submit button), but the opening-in-new-tab persisted. Having nothing requiring data, I had the form create immediately on loading, and found the problem went away. I tried wrapping the form-creation in a `setTimeout`, and the problem returned, even with a time of zero.

It's possible that the framework is doing something to cause the problem, but I don't know what it could be. It is *not* changing the DOM around or in the form. That is exactly the same in the working and non-working instances.

Comment: If I paste that HTML into example.com via Chrome's developer tools, it seems to work fine.  Could you perhaps create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem occurring?

Comment: I doubt that I can create a fiddle that demonstrates it, as it probably has to do with how the DOM is being updated by the framework. A couple of straightforward attempts did not demonstrate it.

Comment: It's within the realm of possibility that the framework is overriding the `submit` event of all forms, and you've encountered a bug in that event override.